# send email for out of stock

Tags: magento-1.7, event-observer, stock

How to send sms when an item quantity is out of stock in magento ?
i have used :

```
<catalog_product_save_before>
    <observers>
        <Metro_Notify>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>notify/Productobserver</class>
            <method>productSaveBefore</method>
        </Metro_Notify>
    </observers>
</catalog_product_save_before>
```

in my observer

```
private function lowStockReportSendEmail($product,$toEmailAddress)
{
    $stockItem = $observer->getEvent();
    Mage::log($stockItem,null,'stockitem.null');

    if($stockItem->getQty() < $stockItem->getNotifyStockQty())
    {
       //stock is lower than the notify amount, send email
       $product = $observer->getProduct();  
       $productName =  $product->getName();
       $productId =  $product->getId();
       $supplierId = $product->getSeller_id();
       $supplierData = $this->_getSupplierData($supplierId);

       // $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($stockItem->getProductId());

        $body = "{$productName} :: {$product->getSku()} just Ran out of stock:\n\n";
        $body .= "Current Qty: {$stockItem->getQty()}\n";
        $body .= "Low Stock Date: {$stockItem->getLowStockDate()}\n";

        $vars['PRODUCTID'] = $productData->getId();
        $vars['PRODUCTNAME'] = $productData->getName();
        $vars['SUPPLIERNAME'] = $supplierData->getFirstname();          
        $vars['SUPPLIERNO'] = $supplierData->getSupplier_no();
        $vars['QTY'] = $stockItem->getQty();
        $vars['PREVIOUSQTY'] = $stockItem->getQty() - $stockItem->getOrigData('qty');

        $categoryManagerTemplateId = 'categorymanager_template_lowstock_report';
        $adminTemplateId = 'admin_template_lowstock_report';
        $fromEmailId = $supplierData->getEmail();
        $sender = array('name' => $fromEmailId,'email' => $fromEmailId);    

        if(!empty($toEmailAddress))
        {
            $categoryManagerEmail = $toEmailAddress;                
            $adminEmail = $toEmailAddress;  
        }   
        else
        {
            $categoryManagerEmail = $supplierData->getSupplier_cat_manager_email();
            $adminEmail = $this->_getAdminEmailAddress();                           
            $this->log('categoryManagerEmail',$categoryManagerEmail);
            $this->log('adminEmail',$adminEmail);
        }

        /* $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
        $templateId = 'supplier_product_stock_update';
        $fromEmailId = $supplierData->getEmail();               
        $sender = array('name' => $fromEmailId,'email' => $fromEmailId);
        $toEmail = $supplierData->getSupplier_cat_manager_email();
        $name = $supplierData->getFirstname();
        $mailSubject = "Supplier Low Stock Notification"; */
        $name = $supplierData->getFirstname();

        $mailCategorySubject = "Out of Stock".$productName."(".$productId.")";
        $mailAdminSubject="Out of Stock".$supplierName;

        $this->_sendNotifyEmail($categoryManagerTemplateId, $sender, $categoryManagerEmail, $name, $mailCategorySubject,$vars, $storeId);
        $this->_sendNotifyEmail($adminTemplateId, $sender, $adminEmail, $name, $mailAdminSubject,$vars, $storeId);
        $this->log('LowStockReportEmail',$vars);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share what you get in your log fiel when you `Mage::log($stockItem,null,'stockitem.null');` please?

Comment: Hi, Its not entering into tat function itself, i have used the event <cataloginventory_stock_item_save_after>

Comment: sorry mate, didn't see your response and posted my answer already... So is the problem that the function is not called at all, or it is called ut not getting anything? can you edit and supply your function that calls `lowStockReportSendEmail` please? I believve it is `productSaveBefore` from your config.xml

Comment: wait, your using the `cataloginventory_stock_item_save_after` event?? your xml snipped says your hooking the `catalog_product_save_before` event?

Comment: namespace/module/Model/Notifier.php.    In my  namespace/module/Model/Productobserver.php , i am using the same function with $observer as parameter

Answer (score 2):

`catalog_product_save_before` is only triggered when the product is saved from the backend, **not** when stock decreases after ordering. You need to observe `sales_order_place_after` as well (unfortunately you cannot use any event related to the stock item model, because Magento uses an optimized SQL query to decrease stock for all ordered items at once, bypassing the model).

An alternative (that's how I solved it), is to rewrite `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock` and add an additional event:

```
<?php
/**
 * Add events to observe stock qty change
 * 
 * @author Fabian Schmengler
 *
 */
class SGH_ShippingExpress_Model_CatalogInventory_Stock
    extends Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock
{
    const EVENT_CORRECT_STOCK_ITEMS_QTY_BEFORE = 'cataloginventory_stock_item_correct_qty_before';
    const EVENT_CORRECT_STOCK_ITEMS_QTY_AFTER = 'cataloginventory_stock_item_correct_qty_after';

    /**
     * (non-PHPdoc)
     * @see Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock::registerProductsSale()
     */
    public function registerProductsSale($items)
    {
        Mage::dispatchEvent(self::EVENT_CORRECT_STOCK_ITEMS_QTY_BEFORE, array(
            'stock'     => $this,
            'items_obj' => (object)array('items' => &$items),
            'operator'  => '+'
        ));
        $result = parent::registerProductsSale($items);
        Mage::dispatchEvent(self::EVENT_CORRECT_STOCK_ITEMS_QTY_AFTER, array(
            'stock'          => $this,
            'items'          => $items,
            'fullsave_items' => $result,
            'operator'       => '+'
        ));
        return $result;
    }
    /**
     * (non-PHPdoc)
     * @see Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock::revertProductsSale()
     */
    public function revertProductsSale($items)
    {
        Mage::dispatchEvent(self::EVENT_CORRECT_STOCK_ITEMS_QTY_BEFORE, array(
            'stock'     => $this,
            'items_obj' => (object)array('items' => &$items),
            'operator'  => '-'
        ));
        $result = parent::revertProductsSale($items);
        Mage::dispatchEvent(self::EVENT_CORRECT_STOCK_ITEMS_QTY_BEFORE, array(
            'stock'          => $this,
            'items'          => $items,
            'fullsave_items' => $result,
            'operator'       => '-'
        ));
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Then the observer for `cataloginventory_stock_item_correct_qty_after` can look like this:

```
    /**
     * @var $items array array($productId => array('qty'=>$qty, 'item'=>$stockItem))
     */
    $items = $observer->getItems();
    foreach ($items as $productId => $item) {
        $stockItem = $item['item'];
        $product = $stockItem->getProduct();

        // Do anything you need with $stockItem and $product here

    }
```

I recommend not to check if they are out of stock at this point, but to add the products to a queue that is processed by a cronjob, to minimize additional load time for the user.

Comment: it will be nice if you can show how can we fetch inventory data using this event.+1 for this awesomeness

Comment: I added some more awesomeness instead ;)

Comment: this is what I call Perfection. You are a Mage Hero... I love this. I wish I can upvote this 5 times more. Kudos :D

Comment: `sales_order_place_after` is there any way to fetch `getNotifyStockQty()` in this event observer

Answer (score 0):

You are getting your stockItem from the `$observer` however you've changed the parameters of your function, therefor `$stockItem = $observer->getEvent();` can't get anything because `$observer` does not exist...

From your OP we can see you are using the `$observer` inside the `lowStockReportSendEmail` function, however the observer is not present here!

Assuming you have the observer, and in that function you create `$product` and `$toEmailAddress` before calling `lowStockReportSendEmail` you should have :

```
private function lowStockReportSendEmail($observer, $product, $toEmailAddress)
{
    $stockItem = $observer->getEvent();
[...]
```

And in the code that calls the funtion, obviously `$this->lowStockReportSendEmail($observer, $product, $toEmailAddress);`

Comment: i have changed it as : if(!empty($product))
  {  ...  since i want those mentioned parameters only. pls help

Comment: I'm sure we can fix this (fyi, I have edited your OP as your code blocks where broken, it's wating for peer review). Can you please confirm your config.xml snippet is 100% correct, also can you check `lowStockReportSendEmail` is up to date and if this function is called from the observer method can you add that snippet please? It seems that you're not passing the observer on, see my edit above.

Comment: in namespace/module/Model/Notifier.php.i have used $productId as parameter.. In my namespace/module/Model/Productobserver.php , i am using the same function with $observer as parameter.Config is correct

Comment: sorry my event is: cataloginventory_stock_item_save_after in config    <cataloginventory_stock_item_save_after>
                    <observers>
                          <Metro_Notify>
                            <type>singleton</type>
                            <class>notify/observer</class>
                            <method>lowStockReport</method>
                          </Metro_Notify>
                    </observers>
                </cataloginventory_stock_item_save_after>

Comment: Ok, so in `lowStockReport` method (I asume you get here?) You load the product and work out the `toEmailAddress` right? Then you call `lowStockReportSendEmail` right? Well in the later function you use the `$observer` again, but you didn't pass it along! see my answer. If your observer function `lowStockReport($observer)` is not getting called this is a different question!

Comment: In my Productobserver , it is public function lowStockReport($observer)
    {... in my notifier it is private function lowStockReportSendEmail($product,$toEmailAddress)
    {
  if(!empty($product))
  {

Comment: Any updates with the solution mate? or i can mail the whole snippet if ok

Comment: Please see the answer above, you will see I am passing the `$observer` along with the other 2 parameters. you need the observer for the first line of `lowStockReportSendEmail`, also to do inline code put backticks (`) around the snippet, that'll help with your formatting ;) Of course you can share the whole file too, pop it on a Git Gist though.

Comment: let us know how you get on, and share that file if you need some more assistance :) I'm leaving work in an hour but I'll check in the morning for you if your still stuck :)